# In a n-sided polygon with length of side L, can you find the distance between 2 vertices v1,v2?

Tags: geometry, polygons, programming

Assume that you are asked to draw an equilateral n-gon. And you start always from (0,0) and you first draw a horizontal line to the right.

Given the length and the number of sides of an equilateral n-gon. Find the distance between two vertices a, b.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? Please edit your query to show your attempts and thoughts on the problem.

Comment: which two vertices $a,b$?

Comment: You may use the Law od Cosines: $d(a,b)^2=d(s,a)^2+d(s,b)^2-2\cdot d(s,a)\cdot d(s,b)\cdot\cos(\angle bsa)$. If you use the polygon's center as point $s$ then you'll find the angle $\angle bsa$ easily, and distances of $a$ and $b$ from $s$ will be equal and simply correlated to $L$ and $n$.